# Can't receive sms messages?

Tags: serial-port, sms, command, gsm, at-command

I can send SMS from hyperterminal, but I can't receive SMS messages. I just keep getting `OK` response without listing the messages. Here are my commands for reading messages and what responses I get.

```
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGL="ALL"
OK
```

As you can see above, I receive the `OK` but without any messages. I tried the following to indicate when I receive a new message.

```
at+cnmi=2,1
OK
```

And when I receive a new message this is what I see.

```
+CMTI: "MT", 0
```

The index for some reason keeps showing up as 0 even if there are more new messages.

Trying to read the new messages with `at+cmgr=index` returns an error.

It doesn't look like the messages are getting saved. This command gives me the following but I don't know what it means.

```
at+cpms=?
+CPMS: ("SM", "ME", "SM_P", "ME_P", "MT"), ("SM", "ME", "SM_P", "ME_P", "MT"), ("SM", "ME", "SM_P", "ME_P", "MT")

OK
```

This is the [datasheet](http://www.docdroid.net/gbbu/at-document-full-v2127.pdf.html) for the GSM/GPRS Modem, so I don't know if I missed any other commands that are needed to receive messages or not. I have had this issue for couple of days and I just can't figure it out, I also tried a different sim card but same problem. Thanks!

Comment: This command did it `AT+CNMI= 2,2,0,0,0`, now new messages get printed out automatically. However, for some reason they won't get stored even though `at+cpms?` gives me  `+CPMS: "SM", 0, 60, "ME", 0, 90, "SM", 0, 60` so there is space available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935354/how-to-read-sms-from-mobil-phone-with-at-commands - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001622/how-to-read-sms-using-at-on-an-embedded-system-with-limited-memory?rq=1 etc?

Comment: What is the value for the at+cpms command (e.g. `at+cpms?`)?

Comment: @AndyThompson, those links weren't helpful. I already searched the site before posting this question.

Comment: @hlovdal, this is the response. `+CPMS: "ME", 0, 100, "ME", 0, 100, "SM", 0, 0`